# How to make barplot of groups in dataframes?

Tags: r

For this data:

```
class <- c(1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 4, 5, 4, 2, 4) 
prog <- c("Bac2", "Bac", "Master", "Bac", "Bac", "DEA", "Doctorat", "DEA", "Bac", "DEA")
  mydata <- data.frame(height = class, prog)
```

I want to make a plot like this.
for example,

```
   all corresponding to bac2 is 1  so it is 100% of 1
   all corresponding to bac are 2,2,1,2 so it is 75% of 2 and 25% of 1


  mydata=structure(list(height = c(1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 4, 5, 4, 2, 4), prog = 
 c("Bac2", 
"Bac", "Master", "Bac", "Bac", "DEA", "Doctorat", "DEA", "Bac", 
"DEA")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Comment: the provided data seems incorrect; try to use `dput` to convert your data example to code that we can directly run to obtain your data-example.

Comment: Seriously, the `dput` function is better approach as it carries (and show us) what else is going on in the data that you're dealing with in your R script.

Comment: ok it is added  to the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```r
class <- c(1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 4, 5, 4, 2, 4) 
prog <- c("Bac2", "Bac", "Master", "Bac", "Bac", "DEA", "Doctorat", "DEA", "Bac", "DEA")
mydata <- data.frame(height = class, prog)
require(dplyr)
require(ggplot2)
require(forcats)

mydata %>% group_by(prog,height) %>% 
  tally() %>% mutate(prop = n/sum(n)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=prog, y=prop, fill=fct_rev(as.factor(height))))+
  geom_col() +
  scale_x_discrete(labels=c('Bac2','Bac','Master', 'DEA','Doctorat'))+
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)+
  theme(legend.position = 'null')
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-05-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: @Tpellirn Actually you don't have to use `scale_x_discrete`. `ggplot` automatically labels your `prog` on axis. I used it to make a same plot as your example.

Comment: Great thanks. please, is there a way to order prog in x axis in a way to start by the one that has max pro as 100  then lower and lower?

Comment: @Tpellirn please ask extra questions with another question with your new data. It would be much easier to reproduce what you want to plot with example data :)

Answer (score 2):

A succinct way using `table` and `proportions` first, then adapting the `length`s to be able to create a matrix, `order` by `max`, and finally `barplot`.

```
p <- with(mydata, tapply(height, prog, \(x) proportions(table(x))))
lapply(p[order(-sapply(p, max))], `length<-`, max(lengths(p))) |>
  do.call(what=rbind) |> t() |> barplot(col=3:6)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way.
Pre-compute the levels of `prog` so that `"Bac2"` comes before `"Bac"`, like in the posted drawing, and how many unique `height` values are in the data to have the bars white.
Then plot the bars with `position = "fill"`.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(dplyr)
  library(ggplot2)
})

mydata=structure(list(height = c(1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 4, 5, 4, 2, 4), prog = 
                        c("Bac2", 
                          "Bac", "Master", "Bac", "Bac", "DEA", "Doctorat", "DEA", "Bac", 
                          "DEA")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))

levs <- unique(mydata$prog)
nheight <- n_distinct(mydata$height)


mydata %>%
  mutate(prog = factor(prog, levels = levs)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(prog, fill = factor(height))) +
  geom_bar(position = "fill", colour = "black", show.legend = FALSE) +
  geom_text(aes(label = height), 
            stat = "count", 
            position = position_fill(vjust = 0.5)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = rep("white", nheight)) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-05-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

---

### Edit

y axis scale changed to a percent scale.